# Is it possible to store formatted text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, text, formatting

For example I want to insert something like this into a table and have it retain the formatting properties of the text for later retrieval:

Ex.

```
**This** is a *sentence*.
```

Also, would it still work if the size of the letters are altered?

Comment: For the love of everything logical don't store HTML tags in your DB to reduce your HTML or CSS code. So many of us will die just a little inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To store formatting, there will need to be a markup of some kind. HTML might work. If this will be displayed in a browser, sanitize the value to avoid any possible security issues.

If you use HTML, the literal stored value might be:

```
<strong>This</strong> is a <i>sentence</i>
```

Edit: noticed the WPF tag, which has different formatting markup from HTML. The idea is still the same.

```
<Bold>This</Bold> is a <Italic>sentence</Italic>
```

Edit2: Not sure why the WPF tag was removed and "formatted" example were changed in the question, lol. Stack Overflow seems like a strange place.

Since it's been brought up, yes, text with markup is not pure relational data, so it theoretically has no business being in a relational database.

However, realistically, there are scenarios that storing the formatting in an alternate way would be counterintuitive/costly (Content Management Systems with Rich Text Boxes that modify dynamic data come to mind)

So, it could be used as long as the developer knows what the consequences are, it's not used badly and blindly (throwing static/never changing content in DB instead of files), and he/she gets the blessing from his/her friendly neighborhood DBA.

Comment: Storing HTML tags in a DB versus handling them in the GUI is a terrible idea. It's forcing a square peg into a round hole. It's like driving a car in reverse across the country. Just because it's technically possible doesn't mean it should be done

Comment: I agree with you. The question was if it was possible, not if it should be done. That's why I mention sanitation to make sure only formatting gets through. This is the most direct answer, but a more robust solution would be a limited, homemade markup (I.E. [b]This[/b] is a [i]sentence[/i]) so it is proprietary and still tells the UI how to display it properly.

Comment: Though you introduce sanitization and an answer that it's possible this opens the door to an array of follow on questions from poor practice. If someone asks how to do X with a loop in SQL Server which is set based, and a wiser choice is to use set based operations, one shouldn't promote looping logic. Be sure to stress BEST practice and solutions with performance and security, at a minimum,  in mind. Cheers Mate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas. Side Note - My original question was edited by an admin which is why you see the tag WPF removed and my formatted example changed.

Answer (score 0):

Store it as `NVARCHAR` and it will retain what ever you insert. If by size you mean length not something like FONT SIZE then this is limited by the size of the column you set. 8000 bytes is the max for `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` which is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(4000)`

Any visual formatting like font type, font size, color, emphasis, etc should be handled by your front end application. Remember SQL Server stores data... It's not a GUI. Thus, storing HTML or CSS formatting is poor practice and isn't what it is intended for.